# how to get the data

Tags: android

In my application i have two activity .When we enter the data in first activity & click save button . the data should display in the second activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can use `Bundle`

In order to pass data from one activity to another.

Answer (score 0):

u can use Intents, Bundles or any Static variables to pass data from one activity to another

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the [documentation for Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#StartingAnActivity) on how to start a new activity. This also has an example on how to add a 'payload' to the intent, that can then be used in the called activtiy