# how to get the data

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789583/how-to-get-the-data)

hi to all

I checked in all the link of android but i did not get the answer. My question in the first activity when i enter the data and click the save button. It should display in the second activity

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895404/passing-an-image-from-one-activity-to-other-activity.

Comment: and what happens instead? you should tell more about the problem you're facing, and the code would help too. thanks!

Comment: Asking the same question again : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789583/how-to-get-the-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
String data = "value";
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("data", data);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in Your Next Activity:

```
String receiver = getIntent().getExtra().getString("data");
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use intents, bundles or static variables for storing data

Answer (score 0):

To pass primitive datatypes see [this tutorial](http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/passing-data-between-activities-in-android/)

If you want to pass complex data types , they need to implement either Serializable or the Parcelable interfaces.

- Salil.